# USB Drive not mounting

Tags: usb-drive

I am 90 % sure the drive is fine :-( - Was copying data from it yesterday.

Lent the drive from a mate to copy data, now it can't be found, plugging in and out no change - **AAAHHH** he is going to KILL me. Please help :-)

Comment: Plug the drive in and then pastebin the output of `sudo fdisk -l` and `dmesg | tail` See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Pastebinit

Answer (score 4):

Here is the Ubuntu official guide to automounting USB:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount/USB

If you have Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid Lynx, maybe you can take a look at this guide here:

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/fix-usb-devices-automount-not-working.html

You can also try to use Disk Utility, available in the Ubuntu Software Centre:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/gnome-disk-utility/

Comment: Disk Utility fixed my issue

Comment: called just "Disks" now I think

Answer (score 1):

The link first suggested under "Ubuntu official guide to automounting USB" suggests

> Disks (the GNOME disk utility) that lists drives, including USB
>   drives. If you click a drive on the list, you can view its details,
>   and can click the triangle-shaped button (Play button) to mount the
>   drive.

This worked first time when a USB memstick suddenly refused to automount under Thunar File Manager. After mounting it pops up in the File Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try this also: This has something to do with the BIOS and floppy drives.

http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/fix-usb-devices-automount-not-working.html

This worked for me when nothing else did. I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
dconf-editor
sudo apt-get install usbmount
pmount
```

Finally I did modprobe as described in link which worked!

```
sudo modprobe -r floppy
```